# Adding authentication info in Rails proxy middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am using the `rack-proxy` gem in Rails to proxy requests to an external server. Thing is, the external endpoint requires authentication. How do I provide that information from the middleware?

Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'rack/proxy'

class MyProxy < Rack::Proxy
  MY_REQUEST = %r{^/path/(.*)}

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if m = MY_REQUEST.match(env['PATH_INFO'])
      env['PATH_INFO'] = "https://otherserver.org/#{m[1]}"
      env['HTTP_HOST'] = "otherserver.org"
      #the otherserver.org endpoint requires authentication
      super env
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of authentication the other server is using. If its just plain HTTP Authentication you can do something like:

```
env['Authentication'] = 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='
```

Where the value part follows the spec at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#cite_ref-8

Comment: Is there any documentation for these things? I am not even sure if I am doing the right thing with `PATH_INFO`

Answer (score 0):

Following the Rack spec here gave me good pointers - http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC

Had to do:

```
env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic <base64 username:password>'
```